# WPF Converter Issues

Tags: wpf

I have 2 issues with converters in WPF

First, Instead of adding the converter to my unboundfield I'd like to add the converter to the setter value property as follows

```
<Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding FirstTransactionAllocationAmount, converter={StaticResource myconverter}" />
```

But It does not work.

Here's my code sample

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="gdWorksheetLine" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  AutoFit="True" BindToSampleData="False" BorderThickness="2" 
                              DataSource="{Binding Path=PaymentAdjustmentAllocation, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts >
                        <igDP:FieldLayout  IsDefault="True" Key="ClaimWorksheet">
                            <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                                <igDP:UnboundField Name="FirstTransactionAllocationAmount"  Label="AmountKey"  BindingPath="FirstTransactionAllocationAmount"  
                                                   Converter="{StaticResource NegativeToPositiveValueConverter}" >
                                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                                        <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamCurrencyEditor}" LabelWidth="100" CellWidth="100" InvalidValueBehavior="RetainValue">
                                            <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamCurrencyEditor}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="$nn,nnn,nnn,nnn.nn" />
                                                    <Setter Property="PromptChar" Value="" />
                                                    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="FirstTransactionAllocationAmount" />
                                                </Style>
                                            </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                        </igDP:FieldSettings>
                                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                                </igDP:UnboundField>
                          </igDP:FieldLayout>
                    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

Secondly, I would like to create a converter that uses another datagrid field cell value as a parameter, any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use another datagrid field as a parameter you'll need to use a [MultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).

Also, "converter" should be "Converter" not sure if that's a typo in bringing xaml to Stackoverflow or an error in your xaml.